# Twitter Bootstrap 3: different CSS for different size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to apply different CSS properties to the same element depending on the screen size - specifically, a different class when we are in "col-xs" size.

Is this possible using Bootstrap, or do I have to resort to using media queries myself?

Comment: Bootstrap uses media queries, so yes, use media queries.

Comment: I am aware of it - they also come with pre-coded classes and mixins so that you won't have to do it yourself, and I was wondering if they had something also for this situation.

Thanks anyway - if you post an answer I will be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with media queries , this source if helpfull also :

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries